# PXE media test failure - disabled PXE boot now I have a blank screen

Tags: boot, pxe

So this is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/480033/acronis-disk-director-after-clone-disk-error-pxe-e61-media-test-failure-check) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/538796/media-test-failure-check-cable-windows-7-laptop) except after restarting the laptop I now have a totally blank screen. I can hear the fan and the power light is on but the screen is blank. I tried hitting del to enter BIOS as the computer restarted but this didn't work. Any advice is really appreciated otherwise I'll call the manufacturer's support. After the I got the blank screen I opened up the back and checked all the cables and checked that the hard drive was connected ok - all fine.

It's an Asus laptop running Windows 8.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried [removing the battery and holding the power button down](http://www.hardwareanalysis.com/content/topic/72836/?o=40) to get the screen working but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not excluding the Hard drive from the Boot List?

If it's defaulting to PXE it means the Boot Manager cannot be found (although your Windows install is OK) (This is the common behavior in UEFI Mode)

Since you are running Windows 8 please double check the Secure Boot and Legacy Boot options.

If your computer's drive is not GPT it will not boot in UEFI Mode.

Some BIOS will allow you to simultaneously use Legacy and UEFI. But within Legacy mode you can't use the Secure Boot options.

I would double check the UEFI Mode and the Legacy Mode options.

Source: Recent experience formatting a Windows 7 disk and installing UEFI mode Windows 8. Imaging using WDS for both UEFI and non-UEFI modes.

Comment: I will check all this but at the moment it's not even booting to BIOS I'm just getting a blank screen.